# changing the password complexity requirement in windows 2008

Tags: password, windows-server-2008

my client has a dedicated server, windows 2008, in which there was a password set, as it was expire i changed it, now client want the same password again, but when i tried changing it. i got a message for password complexity requirement, how can i change my password back to old one.

Comment: This is not a programming question.  It would be better asked at Super User.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Go to Administrative Tools
2. local Security Policy
3. Account Policies
4. Password Policy
5. Right click "Password must meet complexity requirements"
6. hit Properties
7. Select Disabled
8. Hit Ok
9. Now go to Control Panel
10. User Accounts
11. "Change your Windows password"
12. "Change your Password"
13. Type in the desired password
14. confirm the new password
15. Hit "Change Password"
16. Return to local Security Policy (OPTIONAL)
17. Account Policies
18. Password Policy
19. Right click "Password must meet complexity requirements"
20. hit Properties
21. Select Enabled
22. Hit Ok

Also, if you'd like to make the password never expire do the following:

1. In local Security Policy
2. Account Policies
3. Password Policy
4. Right click "Maximum Password age"
5. hit properties
6. Enter in the value of 0
7. Hit Ok